# Defining trip time in pedestrian lib

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm using mainly the pedestrian library to simulate evacuation of a hospital. How can I specify a given time (e.g. triangular(1,2,3)) for the agents to go from their given room to exit (target line)?

In advance thank you!

Comment: you can't do it

Comment: I second Felipe's comment. Time to reach a point depends on distance and speed, it isn't possible to set just the time component as it can potentially create pedestrians that are moving way faster than humanly possible.